# Convert from wiki to html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wikipedia-api

I'm using a wikipedia api for getting info from wikipedia.
Is there anything for convert wiki text in html?

I've tried mediacloth but i doesn't works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [marker](http://github.com/rdblue/marker).

```
>> require 'marker'
>> m = Marker.parse "== heading ==\nparagraph with '''bold''' text"
>> puts m.to_html
<h2>heading</h2>
<p>paragraph with <b>bold</b> text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also wikicloth http://code.google.com/p/wikicloth/ it implements some things that others haven't like tables.

Comment: Code Google is dead.

Answer (score -1):

You could download a [static HTML dump](http://static.wikipedia.org/) of Wikipedia.

Comment: I think he knows that.